# How to override insall directory with setup.py install

Tags: python, macos

I am using python 2.7 on Mac OSX.

I am trying to install a package using the setup.py file which looks like:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(packages=['object_recognition_by_parts'], package_dir={'': 'python'})
```

it fails an throws the following error:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
creating /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
error: could not create '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages': Permission denied
```

But my site packages directory is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and not `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Can I override this?

If I install using pip, the packages are installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Answer (score 1):

You may define home path by command line parameter, e.g.

```
python setup.py install --home=/home/blah
```

Or you may have to modify Python’s search path.

More details:

- [Alternate installation the home scheme](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-the-home-scheme)
- [Modifying Python’s Search Path](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#inst-search-path)

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local
```

and it will put it in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```